# How to read and get the stored value from ini file in python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, security, configparser

```
import configparser
config= configparser.ConfigParser()

config.read(r'C:\Users\PycharmProjects\Integration\local.ini')
print(config.sections())
```

Don't know what to do after this. I had tried this code

```
server = config.get('db','server')
```

It throws an output from print statement and an error.

```
['"db"', '"Auth"']
configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'db'

local.ini file contains
["db"]
server=raj
log=ere2
["Auth"]
login=hi
```

Comment: `server = config['db']['server')]` Try this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make ini file like this:

```
[db]
server=raj
log=ere2
[Auth]
login=hi
```

and import like:

```
import configparser
config= configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(r'C:\Users\PycharmProjects\Integration\local.ini')
server = config['db']['server']
```

Or if you want the returned data to always be `str`, use:

```
server = str(config['db']['server'])
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who may encounter this and the accepted solution doesn't work for them, Rohit-Pandley's answer is probably correct except for 2 small syntax errors where "config['db']['server')]" is used.

The ")" in the 'server' key call (inside the []) is not supposed to be there. It should read like this instead.

```
server = config['db']['server']
```

and

```
server = eval(config['db']['server'])
```

So altogether it should look like this. (This is Rohit-Pandley's solution copied and fixed)

Make ini file like this:

```
[db]
server=raj
log=ere2
[Auth]
login=hi
```

and import like:

```
import configparser
config= configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(r'C:\Users\PycharmProjects\Integration\local.ini')
server = config['db']['server']
```

Or it return always `str` so if data type is other then string then use:

```
server = eval(config['db']['server'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
['"db"', '"Auth"']

Answer: 
["db","Auth"]
```